# Does adding @MainActor to a @Published var change the actor of it's parent class?

Tags: swift, swiftui

Consider the following code:

```
import SwiftUI

class VM:ObservableObject{
    @Published var keepStuff = 0
    
    init(){
        keepStuff = 1
    }
}

struct MyView:View{
    
    @ObservedObject var vm = VM()
    
    var body: some View{
        Text("Hello World")
        Text(String(vm.keepStuff))
    }
}
```

This produces no error message and works as expected. Now, if I add `@MainActor` to `keepStuff` I get a

> note: mutation of this property is only permitted within the actor

E.g.,

```
@MainActor @Published var keepStuff = 0

class VM:ObservableObject{
    @MainActor @Published var keepStuff = 0
    
    init(){
        keepStuff = 1
    }
}
```

The error obviously goes away if I `@MainActor` the whole class or the `init`.

My understanding was always that a `@Published var` is automatically part of the main actor, hence why you get errors when updating a `@Published` var from any non-main actor. Here it almost looks like adding `@MainActor` to the `@Published var` makes the rest of class no longer part of the `MainActor`.

Can someone explain this behaviour?

Comment: `@Published` indicates that the parent class notifies about changes of the value. It's not related to a specific actor. Nevertheless it's good practice to mark the entire `ObservableObject`class to run on the `@MainActor` .

Comment: I don't have an explanation, but you could use this, `@MainActor init() {....}` to remove the error. Works for me.

Comment: “My understanding was always that a `@Published var` is automatically part of the main actor” … No. Only if the class is isolated to the main actor (e.g. `@MainActor class VM: ObservableObject { … }`) will its properties automatically be isolated, too. Otherwise you have to manually isolate the properties. That having been said, like vadian said, we almost invariably isolate view models (whose sole responsibility is interacting with the view) to the main actor. FWIW, this is what Apple advises 39min into [this video](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2021/10194/?time=2370)

Answer (score 0):

I just did a quick test and found using @MainActor @Published does not make the class `@MainActor` aswell. I.e. any async func declared within the class run on background threads not the main thread like they would do if the class was @MainActor.

```
//@MainActor
class TestObject: ObservableObject {
    @MainActor @Published var count = 0
     
    func test() async {
       // here it is on main thread if class is @MainActor and background thread if isn't (even with @MainActor @Published above)
        do {
            try await Task.sleep(for: .seconds(2)) // put break point here to check the thread
        }
        catch {
            return // cancelled
        }

        await MainActor.run { // or Task { @MainActor in seen in Apple's FoodTruck sample
            count+=1
        }
    }
}

struct MyView: View {
   @StateObject var object = TestObject()

   var body: some View {
        Text("Test)
        .task {
             await object.test()
        }
    }
}
```