# Can I set a published property inside a async function in an ObservableObject class marked as @MainActor?

Tags: swift, swiftui, async-await, concurrency

Say I have a code as below:

```
@MainActor
class ViewModel: ObservableObject {
  @Published var property1: Bool = false

  func changeProperty() async {
    property1 = false //Can I do this without DispatchQueue.main.async or MainActor.run?
  }
}

func anotherFunction() {
  Task {
    await changeProperty()  
  }
}
```

I am learning SwiftUI and trying to get an understanding of how async/await works with the MainActor.
In the above code, my understanding is that since `changeProperty` is an async function, when it is called from `anotherFunction` with await, it will run on another thread and not the main.
With that assumption, can I change a published property from inside the async function which is not running on the main thread?
Does the `@MainActor` declaration somehow automagically make that `property1 = false` run on the main thread without the need for anything like the Dispatch.main.async?

Thank you!

Comment: "from inside the async function which is not running on the main thread" -- it _is_ running on the main thread. `@MainActor` enforces that `changeProperty()` will be called on the main thread.

Comment: Never combine `DispatchQueue` with the new Concurrency

Comment: jnpdx, thank you. From what you say, all the code inside any async function will run on the main thread [with the @MainActor], except any call to a system async task like urlsession data fetch inside that function [changeProperty] which will get spawned off to a new thread?

Comment: @Sekar - Basically, yes (though I’d suggest you avoid implementation-specific terminology like “spawned off to a new thread”, which is not accurate). But, yes, when you hit `await`, the current task is suspended and the main actor is free to do other things until the called routine returns and this task continues execution. For details on the Swift concurrency threading model, you might find WWDC 2021 video [Swift concurrency: Behind the scenes](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2021/10254/) interesting.

Answer (score 2):

Having isolated `ViewModel` to the main actor, you do not need to manually dispatch the updating of `property1` to the main actor or queue. As SE-0316 [Using global actors on a type](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/main/proposals/0316-global-actors.md#using-global-actors-on-a-type) says (emphasis added):

> It is common for entire types (and even class hierarchies) to predominantly require execution on the main thread, and for asynchronous work to be a special case. In such cases, the type itself can be annotated with a global actor, and *all of the methods, properties, and subscripts will implicitly be isolated to that global actor.*

So, the following is isolates both `property1` and the `changeProperty` method to the main actor:

```swift
@MainActor
class ViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var property1 = false

    func changeProperty() async {
        property1 = true          // no `DispatchQueue.main.async` or `MainActor.run` needed
    }
}
```

Because they are both `property1` and `changeProperty` are isolated to the main actor, no further synchronization with the main thread is necessary. Note, it does not matter whether `changeProperty` is a synchronous or asynchronous method: It can still safely update the actor-isolated properties. (Probably needless to say, you would never make `changeProperty` an `async` method if it did not have an `await` somewhere within the method.)

As an aside, once you have adopted Swift concurrency, you should probably refrain from dispatching to GCD queues at all. Stick with the Swift concurrency API.

---

References:

- If you are curious about the Swift concurrency threading model, WWDC 2021 video [Swift concurrency: Behind the scenes](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2021/10254/) may be interesting.
- For more information on actors, actor-isolation, and the `MainActor` global actor, see [Protect mutable state with Swift actors](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2021/10133/).
- In [Swift concurrency: Update a sample app](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2021/10194/?time=2370), they talk about the convention regarding isolating `ObservableObject` classes (such as a view model) to the main actor.

Answer (score -1):

Your object for an async view-related action would not normally be main actor because if you want to have your async func run on the main thread you might as-well declare it in the `View` struct which already is main actor.

We don't need objects with complicated cancellation logic to do async work since `.task` was introduced, but if you really want one for some reason then I've seen Apple using this pattern (`StoreActor.swift` in the FoodTruck sample):

```
class Fetcher: ObservableObject {
  @Published var property1: Bool = false

  // background thread because this class is not @MainActor
  func changeProperty() async {
    let value = await Helper.anotherFunction()
    Task { @MainActor in
        property1 = value
    }
  }
}
```

If you call `await fetcher.changeProperty` from a `.task` all of it inc. that child `@MainActor` `Task` will be cancelled when the underlying `UIView` disappears, very neat.

Again though, it would be a lot simpler to forget the object and just do:

```
@State var property = false

.task {
    property = await Anything.someAsyncFunc()
}
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with the OP’s question re dispatch to the main actor/queue/thread when enjoying actor isolation. Worse, it leaves the OP to infer the opposite, that one should use `Task { @MainActor in … }` in lieu of `@MainActor` isolation, which is not well advised. If you don’t want to isolate the whole type to the main actor, fine, (I completely disagree with your logic on that score, but that’s a matter of opinion, so I will not belabor that), at least isolate `property1` (e.g. `@MainActor @Published var property1 = false`). Relying solely on `Task { @MainActor in … }` is brittle.

Comment: I'm aware of the brand new `@MainActor @Published` but it isn't in any Apple sample code yet and I haven't fully tested it so didn't want to recommend it incase there are complications. E.g. this person things it makes the class @MainActor too so I need to test that https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75624448/does-adding-mainactor-to-a-published-var-change-the-actor-of-its-parent-class

Comment: Apple generally advises that `ObservableObject` for the UI should just isolate the whole class on the main actor, like the OP did (e.g., see the discussion [~39 min into Swift concurrency: Update a sample app](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2021/10194/?time=2370])), so you just don't see it a lot. But isolating properties to a global actor has been there since the very start (e.g., see [SE-0316: Global actors: Using global actors on functions and data](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/main/proposals/0316-global-actors.md#using-global-actors-on-functions-and-data)).

Comment: The difference in that video at 39mins is CoffeeData is the model store ObservableObject which is why they have refactored the background work on the model data to an actor. The OP for is talking about view data and I believe is trying to do something async for the view since they named it "ViewModel". It's best they just use my last snippet and use the View structs async context since it has many advantages over trying to implement it in a `@StateObject`.

Comment: That’s not remotely what that video is saying, but that’s not relevant here. My point is that one could conceivably debate *how* you mark the property as actor isolated (the whole class or just the property), but not *whether* you actor-isolate it or not. It is really bad advice to suggest that you should *not* actor-isolate the property, and instead fall back to the brittle pattern of having to manually remember to dispatch it back to the main actor everytime you update it, and rely on runtime exceptions when you forget to do so.